# Why can't I return a closure that returns a view from a Swift function declared as "-> () -> some View"?

Tags: swift, swiftui, closures, opaque-types

```swift
struct NavLinkLabel: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        }
        .padding()
        .border(.bar)
    }
}

func lbl(_ text: String) -> () -> some View {
    return {
        NavLinkLabel(text: text) //ERROR
    }
}
```

This gives me an error on the marked line:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NavLinkLabel' to closure result type 'some View'

This is despite the fact that NavLinkLabel conforms to the View protocol.

If I replace the offending line with `NavLinkLabel(text: text).body`, I get this:

> Cannot convert value of type 'some View' (type of 'NavLinkLabel.body') to closure result type 'some View' (result of 'lbl')

Why can't it convert a conforming type, or an even an opaque type, to an opaque type of the same protocol? I don't doubt there's a better way to do this anyway, but I'm just experimenting and wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: seems to me you are trying to reimplement ViewModifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to return a closure (ie, actually a builder) then the simplest (and actually the one) variant is just to declare what is known concrete type (as we know what's returned), ie

```
func lbl(_ text: String) -> () -> NavLinkLabel {     // << here !!
    return {
        NavLinkLabel(text: text)
    }
}
```

Otherwise just return `NavLinkLabel(text: text)` directly, because the `some` support is limited in swift (at v5.6 time). It is only

> 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions

means direct return type, not return of returned closure - it is out of scope.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. So you're saying it isn't possible to have a function return a closure which in turn returns an opaque type? I'd have expected it to give a more descriptive error message then, especially in a programming language created by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You got an error because you wrap the returned `View` inside a `closure{}`. Also your return should be `-> some View` not `-> () -> some View`.

Try this instead:

```
func lbl(_ text: String) -> some View {
    return DetailView(viewModel: vm) //this is my actual view and it worked
}
```

Comment: But supposing I did want it wrapped inside a closure, why wouldn't `-> () -> some View` work? (Though I guess @Asperi already answered that)